# Pandas groupby perform computation that uses multiple rows and columns per group

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following data:

```
,       Animal,     Color,      Rank,       X
0,         c,         b,         1,         9
1,         c,         b,         2,         8
2,         c,         b,         3,         7
3,         c,         r,         1,         6
4,         c,         r,         2,         5
5,         c,         r,         3,         4
6,         d,         g,         1,         3
7,         d,         g,         2,         2
8,         d,         g,         3,         1
```

I now want to group by `["Animal", "Color"]` and, for every group, I want to subtract the `X` value that corresponds to `Rank` equal to `1` from every other `X` value in that group.

Currently I am looping like this:

```py
dfs = []
for _, tmp in df.groupby(["Animal","Color"]):
    baseline = tmp.loc[tmp["Rank"]==1,"X"].to_numpy()
    tmp["Y"] = tmp["X"]-baseline 
    dfs.append(tmp)


dfs = pd.concat(dfs)
```

This yields the right result, i.e.,

[image]

The whole process is however really slow and I would prefer to use `apply` or `transform` instead.
My problem is that I am unable to find a way to use the whole grouped data within `apply` or `transform`.

Is there a way to accelerate my computation?

For completeness, here's my MWE:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Animal": {0: "c", 1: "c", 2: "c", 3: "c", 4: "c", 5: "c", 6: "d", 7: "d", 8: "d"},
        "Color": {0: "b", 1: "b", 2: "b", 3: "r", 4: "r", 5: "r", 6: "g", 7: "g", 8: "g"},
        "Rank": {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 3},
        "X": {0: 9, 1: 8, 2: 7, 3: 6, 4: 5, 5: 4, 6: 3, 7: 2, 8: 1},
    }
)
```

Comment: How many rows do you have?

Comment: The number of rows will be somewhere between 10k and 100k, with somewhere between 5 and 10 entries in every group. However, I will have to run this aggregation multiple times independently.

Comment: Since you already have `Rank`, wouldn't the answer simply be `df.Rank*-1+1`?

Comment: @ouroboros1 I am not sure I understand that comment correctly.I only picked the `X` values to look like this for the MWE. In reality, think of  them as arbitrary measurements.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's the same as OP's solution performance-wise, but a little bit shorter:

```
# Just to be sure that we won't mess up the ordering after groupby
df.sort_values(['Animal', 'Color', 'Rank'], inplace=True)
df['Y'] = df['X'] - df.groupby(['Animal', 'Color']).transform('first')['X']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution that is faster (at least in my use case):

```py
# get a unique identifier for every group
df["_group"] = df.groupby(["Animal", "Color"]).ngroup()

# for every group, get that identifier and the value X to be subtracted
baseline = df.loc[df["Rank"] == 1, ["_group", "X"]]

# merge the original data and the baseline data on the group
# this gives a new column with the Rank==1 value of X
df = pd.merge(df, baseline, on="_group", suffixes=("", "_baseline"))

# perform arithmetic
df["Y"] = df["X"] - df["X_baseline"]

# drop intermediate columns
df.drop(columns=["_group", "X_baseline"], inplace=True)
```